# Google Sheets Conditional Email Alerts regarding Vehicle Service Due

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Noob alert.
I am in the process of building a vehicle maintenance records sheet as I can't find a program that does what I want without doing far too much.

I cannot get the email part to give any results. On the "Maint Sched." sheet in column "O" I am predicting todays hours (I'm using "hours" for everything vehicles and equipment). I want an email to send when the values in column "O" approach the values in columns "S" and "U". It would be nice to have a value spot in "Settings" to determine (("Hours" - "Settings Value") = (Columns "S" or "U").

1. In my current code the email wont ever send, not even when values match (no errors, just no email received)
2. Email should send once when column "O" value is equal or above columns "S" or "U"
3. Adjustable "Settings" value for "before equal" notification

Here is the sheets link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9RzPQ5gNJWZVS4jtuVFhPg3icGJY0g5-pFCj1Lvkv0/edit?usp=sharing

This is the (copied and adapted) script:

```
  var vehicleCurrentMiles = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched.").getRange("Q4"); 
  var vehicleCMiles = vehicleCurrentMiles.getValue();
  var vehicleDueMiles = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched.").getRange("S4"); 
  var vehicleDMiles = vehicleDueMiles.getValue();
  var vehicle = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched.").getRange("A4"); 
  if (vehicleCMiles = vehicleDMiles){
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("B1");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    var message = 'The ' + vehicle + 'is due for service ';
    var subject = 'Service Due';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Thank you for all your help!

Edit 11/12:

Here is my updated code that is getting me the results I want. The problem I have now is that I need to increase the range from 1 row to row 4 to bottom (A4:A etc).

```
  var vehicleCurrentMiles = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched.").getRange("Q4:Q"); 
  var vehicleCMiles = vehicleCurrentMiles.getValue();
  var vehicleDueMiles = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched.").getRange("S4:S"); 
  var vehicleDMiles = vehicleDueMiles.getValue();
  var equipValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Maint Sched.").getRange("A4:A"); 
  var equipV = equipValue.getValue();  
  var vehiclevariable = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("B2");   
  var vehicleV = vehiclevariable.getValue();  
  if (vehicleCMiles >= (vehicleDMiles - vehicleV)) {
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Settings").getRange("B1");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    var message = 'The ' + equipV + ' is at ' + vehicleCMiles +' miles/hours and is due for service at ' + vehicleDMiles + '.';
    var subject = 'Service Due';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

As you can see I increased the range in my code and yet it is only returning results from row 4. I believe I need a loop code?

Comment: Does `emailAddress` contain a valid email address? @Guineachaser

Comment: Your if statement contains a an assignment not a comparison try ==

Comment: @ale13 Yes, the email is my work email, the first thing I did was verify that its correct. I did not include that specific email here for reasons.

Comment: @Cooper, can you clarify? I'm sorry, I am not fluent with this in any way....

Comment: [assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)  vs [Equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality)

Comment: @cooper thanks! I'll try that yet.

Answer (score 0):

#### There are multiple issues with your code:

- you are using `getValue()` in order to get *values* from a range > you should specify the range and then use `getValues()`;
- you are trying to perform operations on the arrays of values without using a loop;
- you are calling the `Spreadsheet` service multiple times, which may result in delays in the execution of your script;

Taking these into account, I suggest you update your code to this:

#### Snippet

```
function sendEmail() {
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let maintSched = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Maint Sched.");
    let settSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Settings");
    let vehicleCMiles = maintSched.getRange(4, 17, 100, 1).getValues();
    let vehicleDMiles = maintSched.getRange(4, 19, 100, 1).getValues();
    let equipValue = maintSched.getRange(4, 1, 100, 1).getValues();
    let vehicleV = settSheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    let emailAddress = settSheet.getRange(1, 2).getValue();

    for (let i = 0; i < vehicleCMiles.length; i++)
        if (vehicleCMiles[i][0] >= vehicleDMiles[i][0] - vehicleV) {
            // other operations
        }
}
```

#### Explanation

As you can see, the spreadsheet has been stored into a variable which is later used to get the two sheets you are using.

Since you want to get the values from a range for both the `vehicleCMiles` and `vehicleDMiles` , the `getRange` method with the following parameters has been used:

- first parameter represents the **row**;
- second parameter represents the **column**;
- third parameter represents the **number of rows**;
- fourth parameter represents the **number of columns**;

Also, in order to get the values from this range declared above, the `getValues()` method has been used. This will return a 2D array so in order to access these values, you will need to use a loop.

#### Note

Please bear in mind that you might have to adjust the ranges to fit your data accordingly. Also, the `for` loop was built considering the fact that both `vehicleCMiles` and `vehicleDMiles` contain the same number of elements.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Apps Script Range Class - getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).

Comment: thank you! Now it sends me all the values in all 3 columns in many many identical emails... I terminated the execution at 76 emails. The code I added to yours is     var message = 'The ' + equipValue + ' is at ' + vehicleCMiles +' miles/hours and is due for service at ' + vehicleDMiles + '.';
    var subject = 'Service Due';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);        }
}